# What are the contact details for Marina Dream Hostel in Dubai?

Tags: dubai, hostels

Is there any way I can get the contact details for Marina Dream Hostel in Dubai please?

I can't find it online, any phone number or email will be super useful.

Comment: How did you book it in the first place?..

Comment: [Hostelz.com](https://www.hostelz.com/hostel/+345952-Marina-Dream) shows this phone number 00971557700424

Answer (score 2):

According to [Hostelz.com](https://www.hostelz.com/hostel/+345952-Marina-Dream):

> Telephone **00971557700424**